# How do I multiply the elements in each column, for every column in a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example, given the matrix

```
A = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
```

how do I multiply the column elements to get the result as `result=[1*4*7 2*5*8 3*6*9]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `prod` function with an optional argument indicating along which dimension the multiplication is to be carried out. For your case,

```
A=[ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
prod(A,1)

ans =

    28    80   162
```

Answer (score 4):

`prod(A)` gives you this result.