# Multiply elements of a matrix along its third dimension

Tags: function, matlab, loops, matrix, for-loop

For programming in MATLAB, how can I write a function that will take a stack of matrices in a variable (let's say `M`) and multiply them together and return in answer in an output argument.

It would be preferred to put `M` as an input argument of the function. And it might be easier to use for loops to multiply each layer to the previous.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

To help start:

```
M(:,:,1)=[1 2,3 4]; %first layer
M(:,:,2)=[5 6,7 8]; %second layer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I multiply the elements in each column, for every column in a matrix in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893295/how-do-i-multiply-the-elements-in-each-column-for-every-column-in-a-matrix-in-ma)

Answer (score 3):

That function is called `prod`.  Try this

```
newM = prod(M,3);
```